# Gaussian curvature and geodesic disc

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature, geodesic

Lets have a regular surface $S$ and $p \in S$. I have to prove that:

$K(p) = \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{12}{\pi} \frac{\pi r^2 - A}{r^4}$

where $A$ is the area of the geodesic disc with center in $p$ and radius $r$. Any clue? I've tried Fermi coordinates but I don't understand them.

Comment: Do you know $L(r)/2\pi=r-K(p)r^3/6+\dots$ where $L(r)$ is the circumference of the circle of radius $r$ centered at $p$?

Comment: @user10354138 I've found that theorem but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Could you prove this formula if you knew that your surface had the form $z = ax^2 + by^2$, and your chosen point was $P = (0,0,0)$? (Hint: for $r$ small, the vertical projection of the disk of radius $r$ in the $xy$-plane will be very nearly the disk of radius $r$ on your surface.)

Comment: @JohnHughes I've tried it but I can't

Comment: Do you know how to compute the area of the portion of the graph of a function $f$ from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R$ that lies over some nice set $S \subset \Bbb R^2$? (i.e., the area of $f(S)$?) Without that knowledge, you're certainly not going to able to prove anything about $A$, which is essential to getting to the result you need.

Comment: @JohnHughes I guess I'd use that to find the area I should integrate the norm of the normal vector ($Xu x Xv$)?

Comment: Go ahead and use MathJax, even in comments. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. And while you're at it, explain what "X" means, when the function you're working with is $f$.